# Showing 'elf_diff:command not found'

Tags: command-line

Trying to run the command 'elf_diff' from github, but getting 'elf_diff' command not found after doing what was under "setup" from [GitHub](https://github.com/CapeLeidokos/elf_diff)

Although 'elf_diff' is there in `/usr/lib`, it's not usable.

Answer (score 0):

Your compile failed so the binary doesn't exist to begin with.

You don't have the requisite compile dependencies - `python3-pip` - installed so the compile fails because you don't have the Python requirements.

Start by installing `python3-pip` and then retry your compile.

If `python3-pip` IS installed, then you need to edit the `Makefile` and replace `pip` with `pip3`, then run `make`.

Comment: I have installed the requirements correctly ,with pip3 install -r python/requirement.txt.Do i have to do something with 'make ' by keeping my path right.I was running 'elf_diff' as it is in the image from /usr/lib/elf_diff/bin. In the bin directory there is a python script of the name 'elf_diff' and the scripts path is ~/Documents/myproject3/bin. I was compiling with 'gcc',I am sorry.

Comment: `make` is calling the `pip` binary - it's trying to build with `pip` but that isn't working, my guess is if you type `which pip` you'll get no response.  In which case you'll have to do something like `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip`, logout and login again, and then try your `make` call again.  Once that is all done and built, you need to do `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip` to remove the symlink so as not to break things in the future.  THis is the only way to get the build script to work

Comment: @SumanBiswas I made a revision with a workaround to force Python 3 PIP usage.  This needs adjusted in the upstream project.